# If one column is entered and other column should be made non editable

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

In this sheet.
If we enter "C" Column first then "D" column should be made non-editable or
If we enter "D" Column first then "C" column should be made non-editable

[image]

I have written code till range selection
VBA : -

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Long
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
    If Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
    
        rng = Cells(i, "B").End(xlDown).Row - 1
        If Cells(i + 1, "B") <> "" Then rng = i
        
    End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastrow As Long, rng As Long
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
                                
            rng = Cells(i, "B").End(xlDown).Row - 1
             If Cells(i + 1, "B") <> "" Then rng = i
                                       
             End If
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: If, let's say, something is entered in C5, do you want to protect D5 or the whole column D?

Comment: Yes. FunThomas. Ex - (1) If C2 column is entered then D2 to D4 should be locked (Because for first Order name will contains from A2 to A4).(2) If C5 column is entered then D5  should be locked .

Comment: What is the logic for C2 locks D2 to D4: Missing ID in A3 and A4? Be careful with such logic as your whole data will be screwed up when someone sorts the sheet. You should have he ID (and ordername) in every row. You could use conditional formatting to "hide" it

Comment: Hey Thomas,  I have made sheet protected so that they cannot sort. Written logic to lock is If Cells(i, "B") <> "" Then
    
        rng = Cells(i, "B").End(xlDown).Row - 1
        If Cells(i + 1, "B") <> "" Then rng = i
        
    End If